# spring integration vs spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

We have application where we are receiving file every day and it needs to be parsed and persist in db. File has 5000 record.

Should we use spring batch or spring integration? And why?

we do need to skip bad record and audit them.

Comment: We used bean.io framework for this and command executor pattern.

Comment: But my question is, parsing a flat file, transforming it to java bean and persist it in to db  can be done both in spring integration and batch. Why some one should choose one over the other? Or should be use combination of both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cases, a combination is appropriate; use Spring Integration to detect new files arriving and use the job launching gateway to launch the job. Especially if you need the richer job semantics (skip, retry etc).

See the [Spring Batch documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html) about using it with Spring Integration.

Comment: This was my understanding  too and wanted to confirm it. Thank you very much.